# jQuery each to iterate over a string in newer versions

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I had this code that I used with jQuery 1.7x and it stopped working in 1.10. I can't find any info on it or bug reports, maybe someone is aware.

So iterating over a string works in jQuery 1.8.3 - http://jsfiddle.net/pavdro/W849v/1/

```
var box = $("#test-console");
$.each("1Test1", function (ind, c) {
        box.html(box.html() + "|" + c);
    });
```

But not working with 1.10 anymore - http://jsfiddle.net/pavdro/W849v/2/

```
TypeError: invalid 'in' operand obj
typeof length === "number" && length > 0 && ( length - 1 ) in obj );
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

p.s. I know how to use just pure js version, I'm only interested in this particular problem.

Comment: Try `var box = $("#test-console");
$.each("1Test1".split(''), function (ind, c) {
    box.html(box.html() + "|" + c);
});` Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9mCUB/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because previously `$.each` method was checking if the first argument is an object as:

```
isObj = length === undefined || jQuery.isFunction( obj );
```

And now instead it checks if the first argument is an array as:

```
isArray = isArraylike( obj );
```

Function `isArraylike` throws exception when tries to check if `( length - 1 )` is in `obj`, i.e. if a number is in a string. Try `5 in 'string'` in the console and you'll get the same exception.

**REF:** https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L514

Answer (score 0):

jQuery each implementation changed (as answered by VisioN).
jQuery each needs an array as first argument; see [doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

try:

```
var box = $("#test-console");
$.each(["1Test1"], function (ind, c) {
    box.html(box.html() + "|" + c);
});
```

Comment: Do you mean `$.each(["1Test1"])`, or `$.each("1Test1".split(''))`?

Comment: well `$.each(["1Test1"])` is what I said. And `$.each("1Test1".split(''))` would be an alternative (but rather silly in the case of "1Test1")...

Comment: Perhaps I shouldn't make my points in the form of questions, but did you check [your solution](http://jsfiddle.net/8E5zf/)?